# ADO.NET - How to select multiple rows from a table ? (and count the number of the rows)

Tags: c#, linq

I'm populating an C# Winform application with `ADO.NET`. Can anybody tell me how to select **multiple rows** from a table? I already know a way to select **only 1 row** from a table, it is, for example:

```
private WorldCupEntities wce = new WorldCupEntities();
FOOTBALL_TEAM ft = wce.FOOTBALL_TEAM.Single(x => x.ID.Equals(aKnownIDVariable));
```

And, by the way, how to count the number of the rows after I have selected them ?

Thanks you guys so much in advanced !

Comment: Use `Where` instead of `Single`

Comment: Thanks but i already tried WHERE with this statement: `FOOTBALL_TEAM ft = wce.FOOTBALL_TEAM.Where(x => x.ID.Equals(aKnownIDVariable));` but Visual Studio display an error ?

Comment: Also would have been helpful had you specified in your question that you already tried `.Count()` and how you know it didn't work.

Comment: The displayed error is `Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Assignment3DBS.FOOTBALL_TEAM>' to 'Assignment3DBS.FOOTBALL_TEAM'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: See my updated post with implicit typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<FOOTBALL_TEAM> fts = wce.FOOTBALL_TEAM.Where(x => x.ID.Equals(aKnownIDVariable)).ToList();
```

to get many where Id equals. Might want to change the query criteria though since I'm guessing ID is unique. The ToList gives you a list and getting the count of a list is as easy as `list.Count`.

If you wanted to get just the count where the query's condition is met:

```
int count = wce.FOOTBALL_TEAM.Count(x => x.ID.Equals(aKnownIDVariable));
```

And now for an explanation why Where didn't originally work for you. Where is going to return a `IQueryable<FOOTBALL_TEAM>`. You were trying to set that to an instance of `FOOTBALL_TEAM` instead of the correct type. Instead you could use `var` or the correct type `IQueryable<FOOTBALL_TEAM>` or convert the result to a list using `ToList` like I did above.

Comment: Thanks so much ! Btw, I don't know what is this type of query called ? I googled something like "ADO.NET select where clause" etc... but the result is nothing related to what I'm looking for :(

Comment: These are LINQ queries

Comment: It's called LINQ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx). MSDN on ADO.NET - "ADO.NET provides consistent access to data sources such as Microsoft SQL Server, as well as data sources exposed through OLE DB and XML." It gives you objects that allow you to connect and interact with data services easily.

Answer (score 0):

**For selecting all rows:**

```
private WorldCupEntities wce = new WorldCupEntities();
var ft = from r in wce.FOOTBALL_TEAM select r;
```

or

```
private WorldCupEntities wce = new WorldCupEntities();
var allRows = wce.FOOTBALL_TEAM.ToList();
```

**For selecting multiple rows (zero or more):**

```
private WorldCupEntities wce = new WorldCupEntities();
var multipleRows = wce.FOOTBALL_TEAM.Where(x => x.ID.Equals(aKnownIDVariable)).ToList();
```

**For the count**

```
private WorldCupEntities wce = new WorldCupEntities();
var count = wce.FOOTBALL_TEAM.Where(x => x.ID.Equals(aKnownIDVariable)).Count();
```

or

```
private WorldCupEntities wce = new WorldCupEntities();
    var multipleRows = wce.FOOTBALL_TEAM.Where(x => x.ID.Equals(aKnownIDVariable)).ToList();
var count = multipleRows.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use implicit typing with the var keyword:

```
var ft = wce.FOOTBAL_TEAM.Where(x=>x.ID==(aKnownIDVariable));
```

Then count the results:

```
int count = ft.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

To select all records, try this

> ```
> private WorldCupEntities wce = new WorldCupEntities();
> var listAll = from item in wce.FOOTBALL_TEAM
>                   select item;
> ```

or by using lambda expressions like this:

> ```
> private WorldCupEntities wce = new WorldCupEntities(); 
> var list = wce.FOOTBALL_TEAM.Where(x => x.ID >= aKnownIDVariable);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that the `WorldCupEntities` class is your data model...

```
using System.Linq;

private WorldCupEntities wce = new WorldCupEntities();
var ft = wce.FOOTBALL_TEAM.Where(x => x.ID.Equals(aKnownIDVariable));
int count = ft.Count();
```

The `.Where` extension method gives you the entities matching the condition you wanted, in an `IEnumerable` of the football-team type.

Counting them is easy with LINQ, because `.Count()` is defined as a LINQ extension method too.

You can read a lot more in the MSDN documentation on query operators: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx

Comment: This will not work. the LINQ method does not return a FOOTBALL_TEAM type.

Comment: While this answer may be correct, perhaps it is better to provide a short explanation.